# set var - from partial class name of this

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a bullet menu that is automatically generated and each item gets a class name added to it.
homeSlide1, homeSlide2, homeSlide3, ect...

What I need to do is on click, get the class that starts with 'homeSlide' on this
Then strip out 'homeslide' and just keep the # at the end,

then assign it to a var (bulletSlideAmount)

```
var nextSlideLocation = (bulletSlideAmount + '00%');
```

```
$('#slideshowIndicators div').click(function(){
    $('.theController').animate({
        marginLeft: nextSlideLocation
        },600,function(){
            //callback
    });
});
```

```
<div id="slideshowIndicators">
    <div class="homeSlide1"></div>
    <div class="homeSlide2"></div>
    <div class="homeSlide3"></div>
    <div class="homeSlide4"></div>
</div>
```

Im basically just trying to turn this:
homeSlide1
homeSlide2
homeSlide3

Into this:
100%
200%
300%

Comment: Looks like an ID, not a class name. What have you tried to solve the problem? Please post the relevant code.

Comment: First, those are `id`s, not classes. Second, I would instead use a class with a `data-` attribute, so you get something like `<div class="home-slide" data-id="1"></div>`

Comment: put ID by accident in the example copy/paste...

Comment: They are automatically created, they get their class names from each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$('#slideshowIndicators').find('[class*="homeSlide"]').each(function (i, elem) {
    var allClasses = elem.className, // get all classes
        homeSlides = allClasses.split(/\s+/).filter(function (val, index, array) {
            return val.indexOf('homeSlide') === 0; // return only those that start with 'homeSlide'
        });
    homeSlides.forEach(function (val, index, array) { // use native forEach iterator
        array[index] = val.replace('homeSlide', '') + '00%'; // strip 'homeSlide' from the number and embellish the resulting string
    });
    elem.innerText = homeSlides.join(', '); // using join in case of multiple 'homeSlide' classes
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jqYeN/

On the off-chance you wanted to show this as a percentage of the total slides (i.e., 25%; 50%; etc.), just change the `array[index] =` line in the `forEach` iterator to do this instead:

```
array[index] = (parseInt(val.replace('homeSlide', ''), 10) / $('#slideshowIndicators').find('[class*="homeSlide"]').length).toFixed(2) + '%';
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jqYeN/1/

Comment: Thanks Pete that was a great help, It works perfectly. Just needed to incorporate it in the click event instead.

Comment: I'd up vote you but I don't have enough rep haha! plus 1 for you good sir

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, its much appreciated. I ended up using this in the end.

```
    $('#slideshowIndicators div').click(function(){
    var allClasses = this.className,
        homeSlides = allClasses.split(/\s+/).filter(function (val, index, array) {
            return val.indexOf('homeSlide') === 0;
        });
    homeSlides.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
        console.log(array[index] = val);
        array[index] = val.replace('homeSlide', '') - 1 + '00%';
    });
    nextSlideLocation = homeSlides.join(', ');
    $('.responsiveSliderController').animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + nextSlideLocation
        },600,function(){
            //callback
    });
});
```

Now just need to figure out how to incorporate the nav arrows, but this code can probably used for that as well.